# A question about patch

Tags: patch

I did a patch file with

```
diff -Naur src/bacula.h src/bacula.h.old
```

and give me a file like this

```
--- src/bacula.h        2015-08-13 15:52:24 +0200
+++ src/bacula.h        2015-10-05 19:21:09 +0200
@@ -72,7 +72,7 @@
 #endif
 #if HAVE_UNISTD_H
 #  ifdef HAVE_HPUX_OS
-#  undef _INCLUDE_POSIX1C_SOURCE
+/*#  undef _INCLUDE_POSIX1C_SOURCE*/
 #  endif
 #include <unistd.h>
 #endif
@@ -95,6 +95,7 @@
 #if defined(_MSC_VER)
 extern "C" {
 #include "getopt.h"
+#include "fcntl.h"
 }
 #endif
```

When i use to patch it ask me

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- src/bacula.h       2015-08-13 15:52:24 +0200
|+++ src/bacula.h       2015-10-05 19:21:09 +0200
```

I want automatically patch src/bacula.h  without ask
how to do?
I use

`patch -p1 < file.patch`

Comment: 1. is there a reason the order of your original patch is `file.h` first, `file.h.old` second, are you sure you want differences going from `file.h` to `file.h.old`? and not the other way around?  2. secondly any reason for the inconsistency file.h whereas the output you have has no mention of file.h , it keeps talking about src/bacula.h

Comment: I have made some changes now is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,you must include the complete path
see example

WRONG!

```
--- src/bacula.h   2015-08-13 15:52:24 +0200
+++ src/bacula.h   2015-10-05 19:21:09 +0200
```

CORRECT!

```
--- bacula-7.0.5/src/bacula.h   2015-08-13 15:52:24 +0200
+++ bacula-7.0.5/src/bacula.h   2015-10-05 19:21:09 +0200
```

With the first incomplete path the patch works,but ask everytime to specify
the path of bacula.h,with the second correct,`patch -p1 < patchfile` works fine
and didn't ask for path

Comment: You need to run `patch` from the same directory in which you ran `diff`. Don't use `-p1` either and it will all just work. No editing of patch files required.

Answer (score 3):

Your command `patch -p1 file.patch` looks for the filenames in the patch file. The `-p1` strips everything in the filenames up to the first `/`; in your case this is the leading `src/`. The command therefore expects to find `bacula.h` in your current directory.

Incidentally, there is something very strange about the filenames you have provided as your example. They don't match, and the filenames in the patch file that should not match, do so. I would strongly recommend that that next time you copy and paste rather than free-typing.

Comment: I have edited the patch,of course,because bacula.h.old is the original file,i know .origin was better as extension

Comment: @elbarna, there is no "of course"; I wasn't watching over your shoulder when you edited the patch file. Generally there should be no need to edit a patch file, but if you did it would have possibly helped to have flagged that in your question.